# Script Google Sheets - редактирование ячеек более 1 раза

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, javascript-events

Имеется гугл таблица и доступ к ней редакторов, необходимо реализовать чтобы каждый из редакторов мог вносить изменения только один раз в таблицу и не более!?

Задача практически решена, за исключением если выделить диапозон ячеек и нажать клавишу delete, то пользователь, которому запрещено редактировать сможет данные спокойно удалить.

Сообственно сам скрипт -

```
function onEdit(event) {
    let userEmail1 = event.user.getEmail();
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let shet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var r = shet.getSelection();
    if(userEmail1 != "Главный_Майл_Можно_Все_Редактировать@mail.ru") {
        /* if(r.getActiveRange().getNumRows() === 1) {
             Browser.msgBox("Запрещено редактировать более 1 ячейки");
            
        }else{
          */
        //Возникает при изменении ячейки
        var newValue = event.value; //Новое значение
        var oldValue = event.oldValue; //Старое значение
        if(typeof(oldValue) == null) {
            shet.getRange(event.range.getRow(), event.range.getColumn()).setValue(newValue)
            var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
            var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
            var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate;
            var protection = event.range.protect().setDescription(description);
            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if(protection.canDomainEdit()) protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        if(oldValue.length > 0) {
            shet.getRange(event.range.getRow(), event.range.getColumn()).setValue(oldValue)
            Browser.msgBox("Запрещено редактировать");
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного странная задача .. Какую цель вы преследуете этим запретом? Можете рассказать о вышестоящей задаче? А то пока похоже что вы спрашиваете "как удобнее ухватиться за ногу штангенциркуля для забивания шурупа"

Comment: точно)))))смотрите задача в том чтобы пользователю разрешено было 1 раз внести изменения в листе в любой ячейки, 1 раз и не больше, таких пользователей 100человек, всех вручную отследить нереально, суть в том чтобы человек внес изменения - они остались как есть и более нельзя корректировать

Comment: Я бы хотел уточнить именно про вышестоящую задачу. Это ставки на спорт, аукцион, сбор данных о работе за день итп? В чем причина требования *"1 раз внести изменения в листе в любой ячейки, не больше"*. Большое ощущение, что вы решаете непрограммную задачу программными средствами.

Comment: Это табель будет для сотрудников, каждый из которых должен один раз внести свою смену на месяц вперед и все, далее корректировать только через модератора

Comment: Возможно, было бы правильнее и проще требовать вноса данных "до 1го числа месяца" и потом 1го числа всю табличку переводить в read-only.

Comment: изначально так рассматривалось, привязка к датам не уместна, так как есть те кто был в не доступа и внес правку в начале уже текущего месяца, как запретить вот редактировать если раз внесли и все?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136540/discussion-between---and-kromster).

Answer (score 0):

Очень странная задача... Скорее всего надо смотреть в сторону изменения прав доступа конкретного пользователя с Редактора на Комментатор (или Читатель) после внесения правок, иначе у него будут оставаться возможности править материал.

Comment: смотрите задача в том чтобы пользователю разрешено было 1 раз внести изменения в листе в любой ячейки, 1 раз и не больше, таких пользователей 100человек, всех вручную отследить нереально, суть в том чтобы человек внес изменения - они остались как есть и более нельзя корректировать